# Android MAUI XamlC error : Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022, apple-m1, parallels

I get the above error only when trying to do a .NET MAUI release build for Android using .net7. This seems to work fine in debug mode and I am able to deploy and test it on a physical device.

I have tried to search online but there doesnt seem to be any mention of the above.

I can see the error against two of the three xaml pages in my app, and one seems fine. I am using the following libraries  in my app if that makes any difference

CommunityToolkit MediaElement
Fody PropertyChanged
App Center Crashes, distribute, analytics
QRCoder
Refit

The page with the MediaElement seems fine though

Also I am running VS2022 17.6.4 using Parallels on an Apple ARM. Any ideas what could be going wrong.

Comment: checked this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/-loading-this-assembly-would-produce-a-different-grant-set-from-other-instances-error-message-when-you-run-a-net-framework-2-0-based-application-on-a-computer-that-is-running-a-64-bit-version-of-windows-b4c26f24-78a8-d56b-c9cb-9e2da5f5aea4

Comment: @Rafael, that is about a hotfix to a 13-year-old version of .net framework. Not related to this.

Comment: @Rafael, Steve is right, its not relevant. Only the error message is the same.I am building an Android mobile app.

Comment: @tribal I would start to remove xaml files from the project and check, when this error is gone, to determine what xaml file produces this error. Then in this xaml file I would start to removing (commenting) blocks to determine what block causes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I was using the following declaration `x:DataType=viewModels:MyViewModel` in my ContentPage. This worked fine in Debug but the Release build was failing. Removing this seemed to resolve the problem.